# How to work with CMYK colors in jQuery.colorpicker?

Tags: jquery, colors, color-picker, cmyk

I would like to use the nice jQuery colorpicker (https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker) with CMYK
colors.

To get the cmyk values from the dialog I use

```
 colorFormat: ['EXACT', 'cp;mp;yp;kp'],
```

That results in something like this

```
 0;68.157958984375;68.157958984375;20.1904296875
```

But when I open the colorpicker dialog again, the color is not determined.

It seems that the EXACT pattern is **not** used for reading.

You can test this with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="colorpicker/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="colorpicker/jquery.colorpicker.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="cp-full" value="0;83.782958984375;83.782958984375;4.736328125" style="width:350px" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.cp-full').colorpicker({
        parts: ['map', 'bar', 'hex', 'rgb', 'alpha', 'cmyk', 'preview' ],
        showOn: 'both',
        colorFormat: ['EXACT', 'cp;mp;yp;kp'],

        init: function(event, color) {
            console.log(color);
        },      
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

So, how can I do that?

(I had a look at the object whent init is fired, but i assume that is to late. Maybe there is an earlier event to split the values from the field.)

Comment: Did you try: `colorformat('c, m, y, k')`

Comment: I tried colorFormat: ['EXACT', 'cp;mp;yp;kp'] without success. Your expression is not valid, I think. Either it has to be one of the predefiend formats like HEX or RGB. Otherwise it has to be a character for the coler (chanel) and a second one for the data-type.

Comment: Recent versions of the Colorpicker allow you to create parser extension. You should be able to create one for this particular format using a simple regex by copying one of the provided examples.

Comment: Just to let you know. I fixed some code in Colorpicker which caused some parsers to not initialize color of the button. This is fixed and I've updated the jsfiddle by h3nr1x to reflect this improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/B945t/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin's documentation don't states a way to do custom reading, checking the code you can see that both parsers [CMYK](https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/blob/master/parsers/jquery.ui.colorpicker-cmyk-parser.js) and [CMYK percent](https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/blob/master/parsers/jquery.ui.colorpicker-cmyk-percentage-parser.js) expects the format `cmyk(value, value, value, value)`. But with the following "hack" (add the `open` event to read the input value and update the control color) you can circunvent the problem and show the previously selected color every time you click the control:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="colorpicker/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="colorpicker/jquery.colorpicker.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="cp-hidden-input" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="cp-full" value="0,83.782958984375,83.782958984375,4.736328125" style="width:350px" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.cp-full').colorpicker({
        parts: ['map', 'bar', 'hex', 'rgb', 'alpha', 'cmyk', 'preview' ],
        showOn: 'both',
        colorFormat: ['EXACT', 'cp,mp,yp,kp'],
        open: function(event, color) {
            var v = $(this).val();
            // Use either ',' or ';' as separator
            var separator = v.indexOf(',') != -1 ? ',' : ';';
            var cmyk = v.split(separator);
            color.colorPicker.color.setCMYK(cmyk[0] / 100.0, cmyk[1] / 100.0, cmyk[2] / 100.0, cmyk[3] / 100.0);
        },
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I want to use  __buttonColorize: true__ and hide the input. After a change the background of the image-button is changed. But the initial value is not set. I tried to do the same you suggested for _open_ in the _init_, but that did not work. I also tried to set it with __color.colorPicker.color.setRGB("#b81111");__ in the _init_, but that did not work neither. Thanks for additional ideas.

Comment: Here is th complete example http://jsfiddle.net/kdLpD/. When the page is loaded the icon is white, but it should have the predefiend color. If you select a new color then the color of the icon changes.  (By the way: It is not relevant if the content of the input fields change. Later they both will be hidden.) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great job h3nr1x! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems you've found a bug. It's quite easy to write a proper parser for this format (copy the example "cmyk-percentage" and change the regexp line as such: `var m = /^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*[,;]\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*[,;]\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*[,;]\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/.exec(color);`), but the color is not displayed correctly initially.

Comment: I've fixed some bugs and updated h3nr1x's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/B945t/